# How to use google spreadsheets to check for broken links using formula

Tags: hyperlink, formula, permalinks, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a list of URL's that I want to check the response code for. Does anyone know how I could do this in Google spreadsheet? I have 1000 URLs so it's quite a big ask.
This script does not work properly...

```
function HTTPResponse( uri )
{
  var response_code ;
  try {
    response_code = UrlFetchApp .fetch( uri ) .getResponseCode() .toString() ;
  }
  catch( error ) {
    response_code = error .toString() .match( / returned code (\d\d\d)\./ )[1] ;
  }
  finally {
    return response_code ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may check below code. If the URL is OK, you'll see **200** as a response:

```
function getStatusCode(url){
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
   return response.getResponseCode();
}
```